# Connecting two DatabaseReferences in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database, where for every user i have the ids of the groups, they are member of, stored. I have the names of the groups stored seperately. Now what I'm trying to do is to display the users groups ordered alphabetically by the group name (GroupA, GroupB, GroupH, GroupX, ...). But I can't really figure out, how to connect the two references. Does anyone know a way to do it? I don't think it is possible to filter children based on a list of valid keys in realtime database, there's only equalTo, startAt etc. Or do I have to just load the ids, get the corresponding group names, and order them myself?

Here's my database structure:

```
"group_profiles" : {
    "-MAz5iuen-BpsLWP1TR0" : {   //GID
      "name" : "GroupA"
    },
    "-MAkiUQ7UnIttXy0ZgZx" : {   //GID
      "name" : "GroupB"
    }
  },
  "groups" : {
    "iwfcfGR4TNatxwxpqEAx7ycNfT43" : {   //UID 
      "-MAz5iuen-BpsLWP1TR0" : {   //GID
        "key" : "..."
      },
      "-MAkiUQ7UnIttXy0ZgZx" : {   //GID
        "key" : "..."
      }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or do I have to just load the ids, get the corresponding group names, and order them myself?

That's one way to do it.

The other way is to duplicate the required data from the groups into groups_profiles for the purpose of performing the query.  This is common in nosql type databases, and is called "denormalization".